# Powershell to import values in first two columns of csv files on a condition

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have the following code which is importing csv data and exporting into an excel spreadsheet.
How do I export-excel, just the "Name" column values (first column), if the 'Status' column value (second column) is equal to "Active"?

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Data\mergeSessions\CiscoAnyconnect.csv' | Sort-Object -Property 'Name' -Unique | Export-Excel -Path 'C:\Data\mergeSessions\reports\reportVCX01.xlsx' -WorkSheetname 'vpn'
```

And for the below code, how to I export-excel, just the value from the 'Associated User' column (first column)?

```
Import-Csv C:\Data\mergeSessions\SessionSummary.csv | Sort-Object 'Associated User' -Unique | Export-Excel -Path C:\Data\mergeSessions\reports\reportVCX01.xlsx -WorksheetName 'citrix'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question you could do:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Data\mergeSessions\CiscoAnyconnect.csv' |
Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Active' } |
Select-Object Name -Unique | Sort-Object |
Export-Excel -Path 'C:\Data\mergeSessions\reports\reportVCX01.xlsx' -WorkSheetname 'vpn'
```

The second part is easier because there is no condition:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Data\mergeSessions\SessionSummary.csv' |
Select-Object 'Associated User' -Unique | Sort-Object |
Export-Excel -Path 'C:\Data\mergeSessions\reports\reportVCX01.xlsx' -WorksheetName 'citrix'
```

Comment: that's great, thank you. One more thing for the first question, if I may? If the "Name" column values all have 'LOCAL\test1' 'LOCAL\test2' 'LOCAL\test3' 'LOCAL\test4' etc. How can I remove the 'LOCAL\' part of the value? it's a -like switch that I need to include right?

Comment: @brokencrow I would then change the `Select-Object Name -Unique` into `Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {($_.Name -split '\\',2)[-1] }} -Unique`. It's a calculated property, basically recreating the Name column.